# Animating UIImageView height constraint white space

Tags: ios, swift, animation, imageview, constraints

I'm trying to achieve some kind of "parallax" effect.

Let's say i have an image at the top of the screen, with height: 180 and a scrollview under it.

The initial state is:

[state initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YD5r.png)

When i scroll up more than 32 px, the image should "dock" up, like making his height 45px, and doing this animated.

The final state should be:

[state final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfk5g.png)

In scrollViewDidEndDragging, i want to dock the image up, animated. I used the following code:

```
self.imageConstraint?.constant = 45.0

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0,
               delay: 0,
               options: [.beginFromCurrentState,
                         .allowAnimatedContent,
                         .allowUserInteraction],
               animations: {
                self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: { _ in
    completion()
})
```

The problem is that the image is set to 45 height, but only the image, and a blank space remains ( the initial height-final height ) and that space is animated.
Basically, with no deceleration, when scrollDidEndDragging i want to animate the height of the image and this does not work as expected.

Looks like this:

[during animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfOW3.png)

What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Write your code in this way it will work hopefully,

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5)
{
    self. self.imageConstraint.constant = 45.0
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded();
}
```

Do let me if it doesn't. Thanks

Comment: same thing, no change

Comment: check your constraint please. Are you using the correct constraint or not ?

Comment: if that's the case, then you should use ScrollViewDelegate and while scrolling just change image constraint. That's a great hack

Comment: No ..  Main View -> { 1.Safe Area, 2.Scroll View, 3.ImageView }
@Najam i tried this but i need to dock at drag end

Comment: friend, you have to change the order of views first, make it as 1-Safe Area, 2-ImageView, 3- ScrollView
Just for debugging purpose, do it and then tell me again